# re-order a table based on sort column and another column value

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, refactoring

I have a table which has a `sort_no` column and the sort values are belonging to `q_id` which corresponds to  question id. But, it does not include proper sorting values. Sometimes, the sort numbers are being repeated for different records with the same `q_id`. I have to refactor this table with unique sort numbers for each question.

This is a sample data I already have:

```
 id |   name  | sort_no | q_id
-------------------------------
 1  |  val_1  |    1    | 21
 2  |  val_2  |    2    | 21
 3  |  val_3  |    1    | 32
 4  |  val_4  |    3    | 21
 5  |  val_5  |    2    | 32
 6  |  val_6  |    2    | 32
 7  |  val_7  |    1    | 25
 8  |  val_8  |    1    | 21
 9  |  val_9  |    1    | 21
-------------------------------
```

This is what it should be:

```
 id |   name  | sort_no | q_id
------------------------------
 1  |  val_1  |    1    | 21
 2  |  val_2  |    2    | 21
 3  |  val_3  |    1    | 32
 4  |  val_4  |    3    | 21
 5  |  val_5  |    2    | 32
 6  |  val_6  |    3    | 32
 7  |  val_7  |    1    | 25
 8  |  val_8  |    4    | 21
 9  |  val_9  |    5    | 21
-------------------------------
```

Actually, I can fetch the records and put them in a loop and update it by a loop. But, as you know, it takes time and resource. The table is huge with millions of records.

I was wondering if I could do it directly in MySQL with a nested query.

I have no idea about the query.

Have anybody experienced this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update test5
   set sort_no=@srt:=if(@grp=q_id,@srt+1,1),
       q_id=@grp:=q_id
 where (0,0)=(select @grp:=0,@srt:=0)
 order by q_id, `name`
```

Set needed 'order by'. First column in 'order by' *must be* "q_id".

> **NOTE:** before running this query, the update safe mode should be disabled (if not by default):

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` doesn't have to be just a field or a list of fields. it can be arbitrary expressions too, e.g.

```
ORDER BY foo = 42 DESC, foo
```

would put all records with `42` FIRST, then the rest of them in regular numeric order.

If you can come up with some expression that calculates a value that fits your desired sort order, then...

```
ORDER BY somefunc(...)
```

would also work. What matters is the value returned by the function, which is what the DB will use to do the actual sorting.

Comment: I want to manipulate the current data to be what I want. I am not selecting anything.

Comment: on any other db that supports windowing functions, this'd be relatively easy to do, but mysql doesn't have them, s you're stuck emulating them in client-side code, and you'll just have to bite the bullet and start looping on sets of records

Comment: Yes. That is what I am going to do. I wish I could find a better way.
This refactoring should be applied on more than 10 tables and each of them  might have hundred tons of records :(