# Execute SQL UPDATE with user defined variable on each result of a select

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a migration script that will be run once, so performance is not a issue.

I have a table `sb_nav_page` and a table `sb_module`. A module is belonging to one page (foreign key `id_page_module`);

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sb_nav_page` (
   `id_page` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_page`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sb_module` (
  `id_module` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_page_module` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_module`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I need to add and populate a new column `zindex` on `sb_module` that will represents the initial order of the modules within a page based on previous ordering rules.

```
mysql> SELECT id_module, name_module, zindex_module from sb_module  
    WHERE id_page_module = 148 ;
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| id_module | name_module | zindex_module |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|       560 | A           |            0  |
|       561 | A           |            0  |
|       562 | B           |            0  |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following SQL UPDATE does the correct initialization for **one page** (id_page = 148).

```
mysql> SET @x = 0;
mysql> UPDATE sb_module SET zindex_module = (@x:=@x+1) WHERE 
    id_page_module = 148     
    ORDER BY name_module DESC, id_module ASC;

mysql> SELECT id_module, name_module, zindex_module from sb_module  
    WHERE id_page_module = 148 ;
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| id_module | name_module | zindex_module |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|       560 | A           |            2  |
|       561 | A           |            3  |
|       562 | B           |            1  |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**But I can figure out how to do it for all the pages, i.e. for all `SELECT id_page from sb_nav_page`.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131581/re-order-a-table-based-on-sort-column-and-another-column-value/39132351#39132351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using variables:

```
SET @x = 0, @p = -1;
UPDATE sb_module
    SET zindex_module = (@x := if(@p = id_page_module, @x + 1,
                                  if(@p := id_page_module, 1, 1)
                                 )
                        )
ORDER BY id_page_module, name_module DESC, id_module ASC;
```

- The first `if` checks if we are on the same page as the last module.
- The second `if` set the new `id_page_module` and reset `@x`.

An index on `sb_module(id_page_module, name_module, id_module)` would help performance.

Comment: OK, I think I get the idea : `@p` is storing the last `id_page`, and when it changes, it resets `@x` to zero. But it doesn't seems to work as expected. I get zindex = 1 for all modules of page 148. `@p` should be set somewhere in the `UPDATE`, doesn't it ?

Comment: I got it : the is a typo in the second `if` : it's `if(@p := id_page_module, 1, 1)` instead of `if(@p = id_page_module, 1, 1)`. assignment instead of comparison.